# Why do I lose reputation for User Was Removed even when you upvote?

Tags: support

I lost 5 reputation for a User Was Removed, and yet I upvoted!!! I was in the 90's of reputation and now I have 88 for the User Was Removed thing, why do I HAVE to lose reputation for User Was Removed even when you upvote that same user that was deleted! I looked at the info and did not understand why I lost reputation for the User Was Removed. It is so random!

Comment: There's a link right beside that reputation change.  [Here it is](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/user-was-removed).  You could have learned this without asking anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You lost 5 rep for the user being removed, because when a user is removed, so are any votes they made (with some exceptions, described in this [Meta Stack Exchange post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125740/dont-throw-away-all-votes-when-a-user-is-deleted/268608#268608).).

So they likely upvoted a post of yours at some point, and then when they were removed, so was that vote, which is why you lost the 5 rep (so it was likely an upvote on a question).